# Why are two characters in Hollow City switched?

Tags: movie, miss-peregrines-home, ransom-riggs

In Hollow City, Emma makes fire appear, and Olive floats. This is the reverse of the original. In the original, both book and movie, Emma was the floater, and Olive controlled fire.

Comment: Since this happened in the movie adaptation, I've added the [movie] tag.

Answer (score 2):

The Director felt it was "better" to switch their peculiarities.

Tim Burton himself says so in [a BuzzFeed interview:](https://www.buzzfeed.com/kimberleydadds/tim-burton-walks-us-through-the-differences-betwee?utm_term=.evB6aN9Vy#.bfQMEVOJ5) (emphasis mine)

> He explained to BuzzFeed: "We switched Emma and Olive's afflictions, or whatever you want to call them. But luckily we had Jane, the screenwriter, [and] we ran some [stuff by Ransom Riggs]... you know, the author is still alive! He was a good collaborator. **We just sort of felt that having Emma floating would be a bit more poetic and it was in the spirit of the book.** So it just felt for the movie it was a better way to go with it. Because often times in novels, characters get omitted, deleted, condensed and I think Ransom felt confident that whatever changes we made were still in the spirit of the book and so it all worked out very well that way. There was no big fights or tensions or controversies in terms of how that came to be."

---

In both the first book *"Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children* and the second *"Hollow City"*, Emma has the peculiarity of pyrokinesis and Olive aerokinesis. Their peculiarities are only switched in the movie adaptation; they're always the same in the books.